# Better rename downloaded file with wget

Tags: wget

I want to list a list of files using wget.
There are relatively different URLs in the list.

If the same file name is downloaded twice, but from another domain, the file is renamed and a number is added as a file extension.

I would like the file name to be counted up and not the file extension.
Can I use wget to adjust the schema so that the filenames are counted up or do I have to write an additional script that fixes it afterwards?
Can you help me?

Start wget:

```
wget -nv -i "files.txt" --directory-prefix=files;
```

Contents of files.txt:

```
http://example.com/apple.jpg
http://example.org/apple.jpg
http://example.net/apple.jpg
```

Downloaded files:

```
apple.jpg
apple.jpg.1
apple.jpg.2
```

Desired filenames: (example)

```
apple.jpg
apple-1.jpg
apple-2.jpg
```

Comment: Im dont think that you can set the suffix at the filename level but it should be a quick one liner to change the files names

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid as well, putonspectacles.
I have made here my solution purely.

```
rename -v 's/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)\.(\d{1,3})$/_$2\.$1/' *
```